# HTTP request using hash.

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, seo, web-crawler

I am reading about making my ajax application crawlable. 
According to google's doc, i need to change my http requests using hash, so from:

http://www.example.com/get_data?param1=6

to

http://www.example.com/get_data#!param1=6

I honestly don't get how #! could be handled by my server and parameters taken. So this makes me thinking i have don't understood the general concept. How can i pass parameters using hashes instead of '?'

thank you

Comment: Afaik, you can't, at least not by using generic GET requests. The hash will not be transferred to the server. Please someone correct me in case I am wrong.

Comment: Your server can't read the hash on the server. This is out dated technique. Learn about the history api

Comment: not sure, but i think it would not handled by server side automatically, you must pass it by yourself using javascript methods.

Comment: so what google means while talking about this?

Comment: Maybe you can post a link to the Doc you are referring to. Thanks. :)

Comment: >so what google means while talking about this? 

as I remember it is just advice from google to developers, who cares about SEO and correctly indexing their links, because simple hash site.com/page.php#somevar will be ignored by google

Comment: Not sure about the whole concept, but there are is some information about it at point 2 here in this doc: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

Comment: If Google says to change a URI not containing a "#" to a URI containing a "#" then they are very very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The hash is something handled exclusively by JavaScript, which then makes a normal Ajax request. [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970708/detect-change-in-hash-value-of-url-using-javascript) gives you some info on how you can detect changes in the Hash using JavaScript. Once the hash has changed:

```
var queryString = window.location.hash.replace(/^#/, "");
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "/foo?" = queryString;

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    ...
};

xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send(null);
```